# Register allocation for code generator in MIPS

Tags: function, nested, mips, allocation, subroutine

```
program main();
     a,b: integer;
     function p(name x: integer; var y,z: integer): integer;
         a: integer;
         function f(y: integer): integer;
             b,c: integer;
             a := a+1;
             if (g(y<=0)) then return 2;
             return 2*x + p(y--/2,b,c) – b*c;
         end function;
         function g(name i: integer): integer;
             if (b < 3) then return 1;
             return i;
         end function;
         a := b++;
         y := f(x);
         z := y*f(x) – a;
         return a;
     end function;
     a := 1;
     b := 6;
     p(a+b--,a,b);
     print(a,b);
 end program
```

This is the programm, in which I want to allocate registers for code generator in MIPS. I have troubles with the nested functions.
My registers are:  $2- $25.
The registers  $4- $7 are used for passing arguments, $3 is for passage access link when calling a function, $2 for results of function. Registers $16-$23 must retain their value when calling a function, so if they are bound, they must be stored in auxiliary positions in the stack by entering the function and
to be reloaded before exiting the function. If the word size is 4 bytes, which is the activation record size for each of the code units,including parameter by reference evaluation subprograms?
Also, how many registers and which are needed to allocate?

Answer (score 1):

Since this programming language is hypothetical, we have to make some assumptions as to the immediacy of the visibility of modifications to `var` parameters.  Let's assume such changes (to `var` parameters) are immediately visible, and thus, they are effectively passed by address.

Therefore, for all practical purposes, actual arguments passed in `var` positions must be memory variables and their address is passed instead of their current value (as would otherwise be the case).

---

<sub>*(Sure, there are other ways to do this: advanced optimization might inline some of these functions (`p` is recursive so that makes it rather difficult to fully inline, though tail recursion could potentially be applied along with further modifications to make it iterative instead of recursive), or else, custom generating the code per particular call sites is another possibility.)*</sub>

---

Thus, under these assumptions, `main.a` and `main.b` are both "forced" to (stack) memory because of `p(a+b--,a,b);`  Further, because of `p(y--/2,b,c)`, `p.b` & `p.c` are also both "forced" to memory.

Other than these variables being assigned stack memory locations, you can do the register allocation normally.

---

Also complicating matters due to the undocumented nature of the hypothetical programming language, is the order of evaluation of expressions.  This code example is rich with ambiguity, using variables and modifications of them (e.g. `b--` in the same expression as using `b`), which in C would lead to the territory of dragons: undefined behavior.

One reasonable assumption would be that order of evaluation is left-to-right, and that side effects (such as post-decrement) are observed immediately.

But we don't know the language.  So, suffice it to say that this code is filled with language-specific land-mines and we don't know the language.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This language is like C.

Comment: how are the registers allocated?

Comment: No, it is not like C: C has neither nested functions nor `var` parameters, so C does not define those concepts.  C does specify that the order of operations is undefined and relying on them gets you into undefined behavior, which is a bad place to be.

Comment: The only registers that are prescribed are the argument registers `$a0`, `$a1`, `$a2`, `$a3`, for the first 4 parameters are integer or pointers.  Otherwise, the `$s` registers will survive a function call, whereas the others will not.

Comment: If the language were C-like then both `return 2*x + p(y--/2,b,c) – b*c;` and `p(a+b--,a,b);` would run afoul of undefined behavior, and your instructor would be remiss in presenting this as legitimate C expression.  The latter uses post-decrement and the value being decremented in the same expression (e.g. `b-- + b` is ub, very bad).  The former uses these `b` & `c` as `var` parameters and also directly in the expression (at `*`), also bad ub in a C-like language.

Comment: The only way that an expression like `b-- + b` could be legitimate is to define the order of evaluation in expressions along with the side effect & visibility of `b--` within the expression (something that C explicitly avoids so as to allow the compiler flexibility to do the most efficient things for any given platform for expressions without ub).